# Another thing about css performance

Tags: css

What these is more fast?

```
#container > .classname
```

or

```
#container .classname
```

I know that '>' will only apply it to childs of #container and not to childs of childs.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is so minimal that i don' think it matters much, so don't think about it too much, unless you're working with thousands of elements which share the same class, otherwise your second approach sounds better because you are being more specific.